# Angular: how to give focus to input element when form is shown?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to give focus on a specific input in my form, when I give it visibility (ng-show value becoming true).
I wrote for this purpose a directive:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('autoFocus',
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            scope: {
                trigger: '@autoFocus'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                scope.$watch('trigger',

                function (value) {
                    if (value === 'true') {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            console.log('autoFocus: giving focus to element by id:', element[0].id);
                            element[0].focus();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
);
```

This doesn't work nor in Firefox nor in Chrome.

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/631) to show what I mean...

I suppose the problem is the directive is run on page load...
How to execute it on ng-show becomes true? (sorry, quite new to angular... :-()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `autoFocus` attribute's value (`trigger` inside the directive) should have the same value as the `show` variable, since you want something to happen when the value of `show` changes:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('autoFocus',

function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            trigger: '=autoFocus'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('trigger',

            function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        console.log('autoFocus: giving focus to element by id:', element[0].id);
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

<input type="text" id="b" value="B" auto-focus="show" />
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ex9d6oa4/

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately it's not working, for me... :-( (input 'b' has not the focus, when form is shown... tested with both FF and Chrome...). Probably the problem is directive is run on page load, and not when sow value changes... (I see the console log message only on page load...).

Comment: jsFiddle seems to have lost my changes. Try the updated link. Note that the code in my answer is the same as the working jsFddle code. So use the code posted above.

Comment: Perfect. Working right now. I missed '=autoFocus' in trigger's value... :-)